# Pose of Collision entity

Tags: gazebo, collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to retrieve the current Pose of all Collision entities. However I just can retrieve the initial Pose before starting the physics engine. The complete plugin code is pasted below.

include <boost/bind.hpp>
include <gazebo.hh>
include <physics/physics.hh>
include <common/common.hh>
include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

```
namespace gazebo
{   
  class ModelPush : public ModelPlugin
  {
    public: void Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /*_sdf*/) 
    {
      // Store the pointer to the model
      this->model = _parent;

      //frame
      frame=0;

      // Listen to the update event. This event is broadcast every
      // simulation iteration.
      this->updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(
          boost::bind(&ModelPush::OnUpdate, this, _1));

    }

    // Called by the world update start event
    public: void OnUpdate(const common::UpdateInfo & /*_info*/)
    {
      // Apply a small linear velocity to the model.
      std::cout << "collision test" << std::endl;





      system("clear");
      cout << "frame\t" << frame << endl;
      frame = frame +1;

      physics::Link_V links = model->GetLinks();
      physics::Collision_V colls;
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {

          cout << links[i]->GetName() << "\t\t" <<links[i]->GetWorldPose() << endl;
          colls = links[i]->GetCollisions();
          for(unsigned i=0; i<colls.size(); i++)
          {
              colls[i]->Update();
              cout << colls[i]->GetName() << "\t\t" << colls[i]->GetWorldPose() << endl;
          }

      }

    }

    // Pointer to the model
    private: physics::ModelPtr model;

    // Pointer to the update event connection
    private: event::ConnectionPtr updateConnection;

    // Frame counter
    private: unsigned int frame;
  };

  // Register this plugin with the simulator
  GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(ModelPush)
}
```

Can anyone help? What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2113/pose-of-collision-entity/) by [Max Stähr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/224/max-st%C3%A4hr/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

there is a litte missunderstanding. I don't want to detect a contact between the the collision entities, rather I would like to know the current pose if the collision entity at each time step.
I can manage to retrieve the current Pose of each link but not of any collision geometry...

Cheers Max

---

Originally posted by [Max Stähr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/224/max-st%C3%A4hr/) with karma: 16 on 2013-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-03-28**:
Oh sorry, so you are saying you get a constant value all the time? Is the object moving? Could you also post your sdf file?

**Comment by [Max Stähr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/224/max-st%C3%A4hr/) on 2013-04-02**:
Hi,
I solved the problem myself. The WordPose of the corresponding Link is updated. By aggregating the relative Collision pose with the WorldLinkPose I can retrieve the WorldCollisionPose. However, it seems to be a bug in the Collision Code. The WorldPose of collision entities is not updated at runtime.

**Comment by [Max Stähr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/224/max-st%C3%A4hr/) on 2013-04-02**:
Hi,
I solved the problem myself. The WordPose of the corresponding Link is updated. By aggregating the relative Collision pose with the WorldLinkPose I can retrieve the WorldCollisionPose. However, it seems to be a bug in the Collision Code. The WorldPose of collision entities is not updated at runtime.